# Table loading on Simple model still writes to log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, etl

I have a database on SqlServer 2012 Enterprise with Recovery model set to 'Simple'.

When data gets pushed into it and I check the resource monitor on the server, I see that MyDB_dat.mdf  gets written to with 20MB/sec, and MyDB_log.ldf gets 30MB/sec.

Both files are op separate disks. 
I drop all indexes except the clustered ones.

How can I prevent this IO on the Log file? The database is completely redundant so I couldn't care less about the log.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding on what the log does and what `Simple mode` is. The database is redundant only because the log is there. All modes write to the log, otherwise it would be impossible to recover from failures or roll back transactions. Whatever redundancy technology you use, it also depends on the log to know what changes are there and which need replication. `SIMPLE` means that the log entries aren't preserved after a transaction commits, so the data space is available for reuse.

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve? Why are you trying to avoid writing to the log? Do you have performance issues? Are you running an ETL process that's taking too long? Perhaps your ETL script uses statements that prevent SQL Server from using minimal logging, which would only log the changed pages, not each individual change

Comment: yeah just trying to speed up a 5 hours load, minimizing IO seemed like the first thing to try. Seems funny that in this age of big data and reliable hardware this is still a feature that can;t be turned off.

Comment: Big data === unreliable hardware. In fact, the more data, the higher the probability that some disk will blow up. Reliable hardware means that you'll be able to recover, not that your site/application will still be up and running while you do that.

Comment: Besides, the problem 1)bad log placement (it should *never* be on the same disk as the database) and 2) the ETL process, not SQL Server. Without specifics it's impossible to help, but check [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for cases that prevent SQL Server from using minimal logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. In simple recovery mode you can still do BEGIN TRAN then COMMIT/ROLLBACK, and more significantly each statement is transactional, so everything has to be written to the log. The thing about simple recovery mode is that the log space is re-used as soon as the transaction (or statement) is complete - there's no waiting until a log backup has been done.

Answer (score 1):

In simple mode Logs truncate when a checkpoint occurs. There is no way to write (or update) in SQL Server without writing to the Log file. The number, and types of indexes only affects how fast, potentially, SQL Server finds the relevant rows. You need a commit followed by a checkpoint (which happens automatically or  by having a script issue a 'checkpoint' command) for the log to truncate.

Comment: pretty sure dropping non-clustered indexes makes a big difference on loading data.

Comment: That's incorrect. A checkpoint won't force truncation, it won't even release the records. Releasing can be delayed for various reasons, eg when using memory-optimized tables

Comment: I wasn;t talking about the log, but loading data in general. Never mind, I now the answer is no,. Thanks.

Comment: Please see this article by Kalen Delaney who notes that,'SIMPLE recovery model causes SQL Server to truncate the transaction log every time a CHECKPOINT operation curs.'                                                                                          http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/what-happens-your-transaction-log-simple-recovery-model Not having indexes probably will go faster without indexes but could go possibly go  slower if you are doing updates. The question posed was how the transaction log affects the operations.